# I want a Word macro to be only associated with a specific .docm file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a macro in Word, assigned it to a button in the Quick Access Toolbar, and saved the file with '.docm' extension. My code is stored in a new module under project(MyProject) -> Modules -> Module 1, not under Normal.
Initially everything worked as I wanted: I opened the .docm document, clicked Enable Content on the yellow Message Bar, and used the button in the Quick Access Toolbar to run the macro. No other Word document, when  opened, showed either the Message Bar or the dedicated button for the macro.
However, after some time both the bar and the button started to appear on any Word documents that I open.
I just want the message bar and the macro button to be displayed when I open the .docm file and not in any other Word files. Neither deleting and rewriting the macro nor deleting and recreating the .docm file solved the problem. Restarting the computer didn't help either, and there are no copies of this .docm file in any other directories.
Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question has some problems: 1) formatting is poor. Try to  separate lines two times, and use **bold**, _italic_  and `code`  2) I suggest you to read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you.  You may even post this problematicword.docm to a google drive or dropbox and share here.  Having said that, it seems a security/authorization problem; try to change things at Trust Center and Macro Security.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting. I had thought about sharing the document, but since there was nothing wrong with the macro itself or the way the .docm document behaved, I saw no reason to do that. Your suggestion to look into the Trust Center settings, together with John Korchok's answer, helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Formatting here may be tricky; we need to see how things are going down in the formatted view. If John Korchok's answer helped you, accept it; if not, you may answer your own question and accept it. Accepting attract more people here and increases the odds to be upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAT icons can be added per-document or per-installation. To remove the per-installation icon you are now seeing, choose **File>Options>Quick Access Toolbar**. Under the *Customize Quick Access Toolbar* heading, ensure the dropdown is set to **For all documents (default)**. Then select the icon you don't want to see and click on the **Remove** button.

Comment: See https://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm#PageStart for more on locations to store QAT modifications.

Comment: Removing the button from all documents was indeed a useful first step. I then recreated the button making sure that it only applied to the .docm document.